# Updating a field within a document in MongoDB / Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am attempting to update a few different fields within a document in a collection, and seem to be having some trouble. I don't seem to be able to access any of the specific attributes I am looking to set (which are subject, standard, price). Would anyone be able to help? Here is my code so far, and the newAttributes don't seem to be making it there.

I have confirmed the doc._id is correctly populating.

```
Template.AppAdmin.events({
'click #editApp': function() {


    let newAttributes = {};

    let subject = $('#subject').val();
    let standard = $('#standard').val();
    let price = $('#price').val();
    console.log(subject);
    console.log(standard);
    console.log(price);

    newAttributes = { subject: subject, standard: standard, price: price }; 

    var doc = Session.get('appId');
    console.log(doc);
    console.log(newAttributes);


    Apps.update(doc._id, { $set: { newAttributes }});
    console.log('app has been updated!');

}
});
```

Thank you.

***UPDATE*** of course I figured it out, I wasn't correctly grabbing the document by ID...

This worked:

```
Apps.update({_id: doc}, { $set: newAttributes });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the braces around newAttributes, because newAttributes is already an object. So your updated code will be like

```
Apps.update(doc._id, { $set: newAttributes });
```

Or

```
Apps.update({'_id':doc._id}, { $set: newAttributes });
```